# Error: File Chooser Dialog Appears for the Make.rb file when installing libv8 -v '3.16.14.3' -- --with-system-v8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

Help:

1. I am running the process to load libv8 version 3.16.14.3 and when I do I get these following  messages and a File Chooser Dialog Box from the WINDOWS command shell. Thus I wonder if I still have to run the old Ruby Racer or is there some problem with my PATH definitions?  I do have Ruby, Devkit , and Python placed in my PATH too so it is strange that I get an additional build message from Gem which says:

> Temporarily enhancing PATH to include Devkit

Thanks and here is the process I used:

gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3' -- --with-system-v8

> Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
>   Building native extensions with: '--with-system-v8'
>   This could take a while...(File Chooser Dialog Box Pops Up with Note Pad Icon)

2. Gem then proceeds to bring up a file chooser for Note Pad in order for me to open the Make.rb file while gem is still building/loading libv8!
3. If I click OK on the File Chooser dialog box, everything builds/loads Successfully.
4. If I click CANCEL on the File Chooser dialog box, the build gives me this R/W Error:

> `ERROR:  Error installing libv8:
>           ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8
```

C:/Ruby23/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170106-7572-1b4kib1.rb extconf.rb --with-system-v8
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8
make "DESTDIR=" clean
Access is denied.

current directory: C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8
make "DESTDIR="
Access is denied.

make failed, exit code 1`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I cleaned up my Path because I found different paths using DevKit but I still need to know if  I need to have a VM box installed on my laptop with Linux running as  the previous commenter had said. I even checked my installation steps using: https://corlewsolutions.com/articles/article-19-install-ruby-on-windows-7-32-bit-or-64-bit and that doesn;t seem to be helping.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had decided to just set up a VM (Virtual Machine) running  Linux on it in order to avoid having to perform this library V8 step . In addition to this, Ruby Version Manager  (And I believe RBENV) only works on Linux/Ubuntu and there doesn't seem to be one for Windows 7 which I also need.  There may be something out there for Windows called PIK but I was leery of trying a lesser known application such as that one.